# Grouping by Date inclusivity

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the data I'm working with here

| Accountid | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 08/01/2021 |
| 123 | 09/01/2021 |
| 123 | 03/01/2022 |
| 123 | 04/01/2022 |
| 123 | 05/01/2022 |
| 123 | 06/01/2022 |

I'm trying to insert into a new table where the data is like this

| Accountid | Start Month | End Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 08/01/2021 | 09/01/2021 |
| 123 | 03/01/2022 | 06/01/2022 |

I'm not sure how to separate them with the gap, and group by the account id in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Huh?  you want to create a row for the date range?  Please provide more detail

Comment: Is 08/01/2021 January 8 or August 1? I suppose it's August 1, because the column is called month, so it's always the first day of a month? Better use an unambiguous format in your sample data to get things clear (e.g. 2022-08-01).

Comment: It's MM DD YYYY format, so yes August

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 12c+ you may also use [`match_recognize`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-pattern-matching-data-warehouses.html#GUID-136DAC89-DA17-45C6-9E37-C9892723AC79) for gaps-and-islands problems to define grouping rules (islands) in a more readable and natural way.

> ```
> select *
> from input_
> match_recognize(
>   partition by accountid
>   order by month asc
>   measures
>     first(month) as start_month,
>     last(month) as end_month
>   /*Any month followed by any number of subsequent month */
>   pattern(any_ next*)
>   define
>     /*Next is the month right after the previous one*/
>     next as months_between(month, prev(month)) = 1
> )
> ```
>
> | ACCOUNTID | START_MONTH | END_MONTH |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 123 | 2021-08-01 | 2021-09-01 |
> | 123 | 2022-03-01 | 2022-06-01 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=daff7ebb6ef6703f3517c8f944772fa0)*

Answer (score 2):

That's a *gaps and islands* problem; one option to do it is:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (accountid, month) as
  2    (select 123, date '2021-01-08' from dual union all
  3     select 123, date '2021-01-09' from dual union all
  4     select 123, date '2021-01-03' from dual union all
  5     select 123, date '2021-01-04' from dual union all
  6     select 123, date '2021-01-05' from dual union all
  7     select 123, date '2021-01-06' from dual
  8    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
  9  temp as
 10    (select accountid, month,
 11       to_char(month, 'J') - row_number() Over
 12         (partition by accountid order by month) diff
 13     from test
 14    )
 15  select accountid,
 16    min(month) as start_month,
 17    max(month) as end_Month
 18  from temp
 19  group by accountid, diff
 20  order by accountid, start_month;

 ACCOUNTID START_MONT END_MONTH
---------- ---------- ----------
       123 03/01/2021 06/01/2021
       123 08/01/2021 09/01/2021

SQL>
```

---

Although related to MS SQL Server, have a look at [Introduction to Gaps and Islands Analysis](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/introduction-to-gaps-and-islands-analysis/); should be interesting reading for you, I presume.

Comment: If these are months (2021-08-01, 2021-09-01, etc.) as I assume, you can replace `to_char(month, 'J')` by `extract(year from month) * 12 + extract(month from month)` in order to get adjacent numbers.